# Find limit of $\sum_{k =n}^{5n} \binom{k-1}{n-1} \frac{1}{5^n} \cdot \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Consider $\displaystyle\sum_{k =n}^{5n} \binom{k-1}{n-1} \frac{1}{5^n} \cdot \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-n}$. We want to find it limit when $n$ goes to $+\infty$.

I've tried :

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k =n}^{5n} \binom{k-1}{n-1} \frac{1}{5^n}\cdot \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left[\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{n-1}p^n (1-p)^k - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{5n+k-1}{n-1} p^n (1-p)^{4n+k}\right]$$
Now the first term gives us :
$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{p}{1+(1-p)}\right)^n,$$ but what can we do with the second one?

As I understand it should be the probability problem (it look's like negative binomial distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It seems to be a probability problem. Namely the sum in question is the probability that one needs no more than $\frac np$ flips to obtain $n$ heads, $p$ being the probability of heads on a single flip. In your case $p=\frac15$.

Thus as $n\to\infty$ the sum tends to $\frac12$ as the pdf of the event "you need $k$ flips to obtain $n$ heads" tends to the normal distribution with the maximum at $k=\frac np$.

P.S. According to WA the sum for finite $n$ is expressed via hypergeometric function.

Comment: Actually I don't understand why the sum should goest to $1/2$

Comment: @openspace Because the normal distribution is symmetric wrt. its maximum. Therefore the areas to the left and to the right of the maximum are equal.

Comment: So we need to use CLT somewhere?

Comment: @openspace Yes. Though there are probably also other means to demonstrate that binomial distribution converges to the normal one.

Comment: How it strictly can be proven? Step by step : we have our sum is equal to $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{4n} \binom{n+k-1}{k} p^n (1-p)^k = \mathbb{P}(X \le 4n)$ what should we do next?

Comment: It looks like that this sum should go to $1$, not $1/2$.

Comment: You should use here $n\frac {1-p}p $ (instead of $4n $) as the upper summation index. Then the sum goes to $\frac12$.

Comment: $n (1-p)/p$ is a expectation?

Comment: The original form of the sum is actually much clearer.  Then the upper summation index $n/p $ is the expected value of $k $ (the number of flips to obtain $n $ heads).

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X - 4n \le 0) = \mathbb{P}(\frac{X-4n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \le 0) \to \Phi(0)$?

Comment: It's really hard to notice the fact that $4n = n(1-p)/p$ and $n(1-p)/p$ is expectation.